# Distinguish between multiple types that are essentially Int32

Tags: c#, .net, performance

I have an application which communicates with a database. Each table has a unique id.

When I pull in a row from the database, I populate a class with all of the fields (this is all generated code).

I originally just used Int32 as the type of the ID, but kept finding that inappropriate types were being passed to methods etc.

My solution to this was to create a specific type which I call idUser (where User is the actual table name). The reason for this is that if I try to pass an idSalesMan into a method which is expecting an idUser, it generates a compile-time error, which is really useful and stops me from making school-boy errors.

The code behind the idUser is like this..

```
[Serializable]
public struct idUser : IComparable
{
    public idUser(int InitVal) { this.m_Main=InitVal; }
    private int m_Main;
    public int Main { get { return m_Main; } set { m_Main = value; }}
    public static implicit operator int(idUser Main) { return Main.m_Main; }
    public static implicit operator idUser(int Main) { return new idUser(Main); }
    public static bool operator ==(idUser one, idUser two) { return one.m_Main == two.m_Main; }
    public static bool operator !=(idUser one, idUser two) { return one.m_Main != two.m_Main; }
    public static bool operator <(idUser one, idUser two) { return one.m_Main < two.m_Main; }
    public static bool operator >(idUser one, idUser two) { return one.m_Main > two.m_Main; }
    public override string ToString() {{ return this.m_Main.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); }}
    public override bool Equals(object obj) { return this.m_Main == ((idUser)obj).m_Main; }
    public override int GetHashCode() { return this.m_Main.GetHashCode(); }
    public int CompareTo(object obj) { return this.m_Main.CompareTo(((idUser)obj).m_Main); }
}
```

This works fine, is easy (as it's generated by a tool I've written), and prevents the issues I present above.

However, as my database has about 100 tables it generates a lot of code, and quite a large executable. (this isn't a major issue).

I was curious as to the performance impact of using the above structure rather than just a standard Int32, and I was quite shocked.

Creating a `List<>` populating it, then checking for the existance of some of the keys..

When using `List<idUser>` it takes 3 times longer to populate it, and 5 times longer to check some of the added items.

This is quite a major hit, so I was looking at alternative ways of doing this.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to say...

```
public struct idUser : Int32 { }
public struct idCustomer : Int32 { }
```

But that obviously doesn't work.

As I said above, it works fine as it is, but just has a performance hit. Does anyone have any ideas about how to incorporate the strict type-checking, whilst retaining the performance of the Int32 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect I can explain the performance problem with finding values in a `List<T>` - you aren't implementing `IEquatable<T>`, so any `Equals` call has to box the value it's comparing with. You should also implement `IComparable<T>` for comparisons.

```
// Please don't use camelCased type names...
// I'd probably use UserId, CustomerId etc, partly to avoid non-interfaces
// starting with I.
public struct IdUser : IComparable, IComparable<IdUser>, IEquatable<IdUser>
{
   ...
   public bool Equals(IdUser other) { return m_Main == other.m_Main; }
   public int CompareTo(IdUser other) { return m_Main.CompareTo(other.mMain); }
}
```

You may well find that just this change brings the performance to an acceptable level. It won't help when *populating* the list, admittedly - but it'll depend on what your required operations are.

Note that in most cases I'd expect the bulk of the performance hit to be transferring data from the database to start with; comparing the performance of populating a list just with in-memory data isn't really a realistic test of the performance impact on your *real* application.

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your response, I've now implemented both of those interfaces, and an increase in performance was seen. It is now taking just over 3 times longer on the new struct (rather than 5 times). So it's a step in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: @RichS: Check the last bit of my answer though - how much are you micro-benchmarking code which doesn't form the bulk of your time? (Maybe this really *is* important - but I wouldn't be surprised to hear that really the database is the bottleneck.) Also, can you post your benchmarking code? I assume you're not running it in the debugger, btw?

Comment: yeah, I appreciate that this test isn't completely realistic, and I wouldn't look to increase the performance by 0.001% when the read from the database will take the main chunk of the work. However, once I have data read in, I then do a lot of data manipulation. The examples I'm giving of idUser etc.. were just examples. (did you see the comment regarding 'enums' ? very strange...)

Comment: @RichS: That suggests your benchmarking code may not be quite right. Personally I'm not sure I'd use enums for this, as it's not really idiomatic - it's not like you *really* have an enumerated type.

Answer (score 1):

The performance issue appears to be in doing the following:

> Creating a List<> populating it, **then checking for the existance of
>   some of the keys..**

This is almost certainly due to the fact that your type doesn't implement [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx), resulting in boxing when equality comparisons are made. Implement this interface and check if this improves things.

`List<T>` relies on `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to perform equality comparisons (say when you call `Contains`). Now this comparer tries to use the `Equals(T other)` method from `IEquatable<T>` if possible, which avoids boxing value-types. If the type doesn't implement the interface, it falls back to `object.Equals(object obj`), which requires value-types to be boxed.

Of course, the only way to deal with all performance issues  is to benchmark and profile.

On another note, are you sure you don't want to use a set, such as `HashSet<T>` rather than a list? Calling `List<T>.Contains` in a loop is strongly suggestive of you requiring set-semantics rather than list-semantics.

Comment: Hi Ani, thanks for your comment, I have implemented the change that you both suggested, and saw an increase in speed. My choice for a List<> was purely for testing purposes.

Answer (score 1):

> Distinguish between multiple types that are essentially Int32

What about using enums?

Comment: Very interesting.. I nearly dismissed your comment at first, then looked at it again. I have created an enum with the syntax public enum idUser : int { } and run the performance test on that.. would you believe that it's actually quicker than the Int32 version ? I need to go back and check this !!